# How to automatically deregister EC2 instance from AWS ELB on termination?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

If an EC2 instance is a member of an AWS Elastic Load Balancer (ELB), **terminating this EC2 instance won't remove it from the ELB.**

It will be marked as N/A, and out of service.
Our monitoring system then notify us of unhealthy instances in the ELB.

Our current solution is a boto script that polls and verify every ELB members, on a regular basis. That's working but that's a pull data architecture that bogs our AWS API throttling.

Is there an option, that automatically removes terminated/missing instances from ELB ?
Alternatively, is it possible on a pushed data (SQS, SNS) instead of pulling the data (API, w/boto) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can understand the problem of having the need for polling as you have taken the Pull Design [ poll for changes and pull the boto script to make the changes ].

The simpler approach would be to use a Push Method i.e. make the instance or remove the instance explicitly on-demand.

There are couple of ways you can do;  few ways I can think of

1. I believe the terminate API call will result in Graceful shutdown followed by termination - If my understanding is right then you can use On-Shutdown scripts that can be triggered to remove itself behind the ELB. You can get the help of the [EC2 Metadata to identify itself](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) - the instance ID; so you can place the same script in every instance or make an AMI.
2. Use Lambda function to Listen for the CLoudTrail Logs using the SNS [ CloudTrail -> SNS -> Lambda Invoke ], parse them for the `"eventName": "TerminateInstances"` and then look for the instance ID and remove that from the ELB.
3. This would more like [ 1a + 2a ] - where instead running the boto (or script), you leave a SNS message that would go call the lambda which in turn would remove the instance from the ELB. Would be helpful and easy to implement the logic of conditional removal or changes in use case.